# Change color of selected table cells with a scss style sheet

Tags: html, css, f#

Hi I am trying to change the background color of a selected item in table cells which have been selected.

I have managed to change the background color of all cells not selected by doing this:

```
td.is-notselected {
    background-color: #d7e3ee;
    color: black;
}
```

However if I try to do this:

```
td.is-selected {
    background-color: #9D9D9D;
    color: yellow;
}
```

Nothing happens, is there something I am missing?

The way I am calling the selected class is as such:

```
 yield td
       [    
        (if (---) then
          ClassName "is-selected"

        else                                                             
          ClassName "is-notselected")
       ]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What language is that third block of code written in?

Comment: It is written in f#

Comment: What F# framework are you using?

Comment: the safe template, with giraffe/azure/fable/elmish. This html code is from the fulma library.